# Nuxt.js Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env/lib/utils'

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, nuxt.js

I'm getting this error when trying to run `yarn run dev --port=4000`

Here is the error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):                                                                                                                                                                friendly-errors 16:52:26
Error: /Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/.nuxt/client.js: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env/lib/utils'
Require stack:
- /Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@nuxt/babel-preset-app/src/polyfills-plugin.js
- /Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@nuxt/babel-preset-app/src/index.js
- /Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js
- /Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
- /Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/nuxt-route-meta/dist/index.js
- /Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at n (/Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/jiti/dist/v8cache.js:2:2364)
    at PluginPass.Program (/Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@nuxt/babel-preset-app/src/polyfills-plugin.js:15:34)
    at newFn (/Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:175:21)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:55:20)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:42:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:92:31)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:116:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:85:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:144:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:82:17)
    at traverse (/Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:62:12)
    at transformFile (/Users/jacob/code/artistrepublik/elite-reviews/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:107:29)
    at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    friendly-errors 16:52:26
 @ multi ./node_modules/eventsource-polyfill/dist/browserify-eventsource.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client ./.nuxt/client.js
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt -r dotenv/config",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.5",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.4",
    "@paypal/paypal-js": "^1.0.5",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^4.5.10",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "latest",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "noty": "^3.2.0-beta",
    "nuxt": "^2.14.12",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.18.0",
    "nuxt-route-meta": "^1.0.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.14.6",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.15.1",
    "nuxt-route-meta": "^1.0.1",
    "nuxt-stripe-module": "^3.0.1",
    "object-to-formdata": "^4.1.0",
    "pluralize": "latest",
    "vee-validate": "^3.4.5",
    "sib-api-v3-sdk": "github:sendinblue/APIv3-nodejs-library",
    "vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",
    "vue-chartist": "^2.2.1",
    "vue-material-design-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "vuejs-noty": "^0.1.3",
    "vue-plyr": "^7.0.0",
    "vuetify-media-player": "^0.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@mdi/font": "^5.9.55",
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.14.12",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.2",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-component": "^1.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

And here is my .babelrc:

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "node": "current"
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried deleting the node_modules folder along with removing the yarn.lock file with no luck. The babel version looks correct. This error only popped up after me playing around with some code (not the package.json) - which is an unrelated error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

@babel/preset-env updated,
use old version 7.12.17
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-env/v/7.12.17

Comment: Use [npm-shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-shrinkwrap) or Yarn [Selective dependency resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) if `@babel/preset-env` is a dependency of a dependency

Comment: This was fixed in Nuxt 2.15.2 as mentioned in https://nuxtjs.org/docs/release-notes#v2.15.2. So there shouldn't be a need to use the older version of @babel/preset-env given you can upgrade Nuxt.

Comment: Unless you can't upgrade to the newer version of Nuxt

Answer (score 19):

This issue drove me crazy for a few hours too.

The solution is to add to `nuxt.config.js` into `build` section:

```
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    babel: {
      presets(env, [ preset, options ]) {
        return [
          [ "@babel/preset-env", options ]
        ]
      }
    },
```

Make sure you have that thing installed:
`npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env`

or in your case with yarn

**Updated:**

Then I encountered another error

> *regeneratorRuntime is not defined*

Here is working part from my `config.nuxt.js`

```
build: {
  babel: {
    presets({isServer}) {
      const targets = isServer ? { node: 'current' } : { ie: 11 }
      return [
        [ require.resolve("@babel/preset-env"), { targets }  ]
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      "@babel/syntax-dynamic-import",
      "@babel/transform-runtime",
      "@babel/transform-async-to-generator"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: does not work I did the same thing you metioned

Comment: Like Raymond Chong said, just downgrade @babel/preset-env module to v7.12.17, then it works.
`npm i @babel/preset-env@7.12.17`

Comment: please add your `config.nuxt.js` the `build` part to the question

Comment: @EricChang mine is `"@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.0",` works fine with config above

Comment: @Shirker because nuxt team releases emergency fix hours ago, so this question no longer exits.

Comment: extra babel option in nuxt.config.js > build did it for me, ty

Comment: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>', error I'm getting

Answer (score 12):

I did the following:

npm uninstall @babel/preset-env

npm install @babel/preset-env@7.12.13

Answer (score 6):

lib/utils.js was dropped for @babel/preset-env@7.13.0 and above

as stated above installing the old 7.12.17 might work

for monorepos it may not be enough. upgrading nuxtjs to 2.15.x did the trick for me

Answer (score 5):

The latest version seems to have this issue resolved, try updating Nuxt to v2.15.2
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/release-notes

Comment: I needed to delete the package-lock.json and re-run a npm update in order to work with the updated version.

Answer (score 2):

I had same error when deploying to ElasticBeanstalk

```
Error: /var/app/current/.nuxt/client.js: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env/lib/utils'
```

upgrading from "nuxt": "v2.14.12", to "nuxt": "v2.15.2", seem to have solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
npm uninstall @babel/preset-env
npm install @babel/preset-env@7.12.17
```

Comment: an explanation is often helpful

Comment: working solution

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, There's some issue with the newest @babel/preset-env within the Nuxt.

install the old version and it should work just fine

`npm i @babel/preset-env@7.12.17 -S`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do：

```
// package.json
"devDependencies": {
   + "@babel/preset-env": "7.12.17",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",


    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0"
  },

// package-lock.json
  "@babel/preset-env": {
      +"version": "7.12.17",
     ...,
     "@nuxt/babel-preset-app": {
        "requires": {
           "@babel/preset-env": "7.12.17",
           ...
         }
     }
   }
```

[image]

[image]